# <h1> elements drag background with them

Tags: html, css

Ok, I'm totally stumped on this one. Text within `<h1>` tags causes the background to move when trying to position the `<h1>` element within the `<section>` it's in. `<p>` tags don't cause this problem

I have a background image within `<section>` tags, like the following:

```
.payroll {
        background-image: url('../img/payroll_bg.jpg');
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        height: 567px;
    }

    .payroll h1 {
        color: #193441;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .pos {
        background-image: url('../img/pos_bg.jpg');
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        height: 632px;

    }
```

My h1 is defined in the CSS like this:

```
h1 {
    font-family: "Helvetica-light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 230%;
    color: #fcfff5;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<section class="payroll">
        <h1>
            Payroll
        </h1>
</section><!-- END class="payroll"-->   

<section class="pos">
    <p>
        This is the pos Costing Section
    </p>

</section><!-- END class="pos" -->
```

I move the background down 4em if I try to move the `<h1>` element around the section by adding a margin to the `.payroll h1 {` like this:

```
.payroll h1 {
        color: #193441;
        text-align: left;
            margin: 4em 0 0 2em 
    }
```

The above code does not move the background right at all.

Using a `<p>` tag doesn't cause the background to move until I try to move the element around using margins. Using an `<h1>` tag causes the background to bump down right away.

Again, I'm totally stumped here. I've also added pictures to demonstrate.

[image]

And another picture with the margin property added to the `<h1>` tag.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give .payroll or .pos "overflow: hidden;".

Comment: That did it!! Thank you. I'll give you the checkmark as soon as the minimum time passes

Answer (score 0):

give the h tage float left
then add clear div

```
.payroll h1 {
        color: #193441;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 4em 0 0 2em ;
        float:left
    }
```

HTML:

```
<h1>
            Payroll
        </h1>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```